# Does the 「の」 can be used as 「を」?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-を, ellipsis

Here is the sentence spoken by Kansai speaker.

> そのフォークみたい**の**貸してください。

Other than the question I put on the topic, if the 「の」 is not used instead of 「を」, I would like to know if I can omit the 「の」 in the sentence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Kansai.

「フォークみたい**の**」 means 「フォークみたい**なもの**」= "fork-like thing".

The 「の」 is not being used instead of 「を」.  Rather, 「を」 is being omitted because of the informality of the speech.

You can correctly say 「フォークみたい**のを**貸してください」 if you want to.

You cannot omit the 「の」 because if you do, 「フォークみたい」 cannot be nominalized.